# Is it possible to make the content of a td not wrap?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have many floated elements inside of a td not wrap. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HUc37/). When you resize the screen or zoom and the table becomes too big for the available size, it cuts the first column in two and sends the second half down. I'd like this behaviour never to happen. I'd prefer if the table maintained its integrity and forced the page to overflow instead (with an horizontal scrollbar).

I've tried a couple things, including `white-space: nowrap;` which does not seem to work.

Comment: FYI, `white-space: nowrap` is for spaces in text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about to use th with attr. colspan?

```
<th class="header" colspan="2">Lundi</th>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HUc37/4/